# Simple function call in R

Tags: r, function

Is there a way to do something like this in R?

```
doSomething <- function(a){

  value <- NULL
  if(a > 0){
     value <- a
  }

   return(value)
}


doSomething(-5) | "no value"
```

I'm just making this up but was curious to know if something like this or similar is possible to do using R instead of using `ifelse/switch/case_when`?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, but if I do, you can use `doSomething(-5) %||% "no value"` where `%||%` is in the `purrr` package.

Comment: I love this!! you should add this as an answer!!

Answer (score 2):

There's no built in syntax for that, but you can write your own.  For example, internally `knitr` uses

```
`%n%` = function(x, y) if (is.null(x)) y else x
```

and then your example becomes

```r
doSomething <- function(a){

  value <- NULL
  if(a > 0){
    value <- a
  }

  return(value)
}

`%n%` <- function(x, y) if (is.null(x)) y else x

doSomething(-5) %n% "no value"
#> [1] "no value"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Watch out though:  in R, there are many different ways to have no value:  something could be missing, or `NA`, or `NaN`, as well as `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

NULL is a list. For `doSomething`, argument `a` is numeric.

```
doSomething(3) | "no value"
```

would OR a number with a character, which is not defined.  You can do that kind of thing in Perl, but it's more a bug than a feature.

Comment: What do you mean by "NULL is a list"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused. Do you want to do this?

```r
doSomething <- function(a){

  value <- "no value"
  if(a > 0){
    value <- a
  }

  return(value)
}

doSomething(-5)
#> [1] "no value"
doSomething(5)
#> [1] 5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>